# How do I make a Minecraft kiosk for portable USB drive that boots on most computers

Tags: linux, usb, java, kiosk

Some time ago, someone referred me to a cool website called [Rapid Rollout](http://www.rapidrollout.com/). It worked fine until I tried to install an OS onto a netbook. To put it short, it didn't work as well as I expected it to. It also didn't install USB flash drives.

I'm trying to build a system (or use a service that would create a system) that would open up the Minecraft Launcher (jar) and show it in full-screen with no background. It would also all have to fit into 8 Gigabytes (as this is the most that I can use right now).

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more of a cookbook than a actual answer, but it probably should get you what you want.

You can directly install ubuntu to a USB key, and in most cases it should boot. The alternative would be to start from a livecd and install it with persistance, but that will give you more things you don't need.

What you really need is

1. a login manager to automatically log in an account
2. a VERY minimal desktop environment
3. that desktop environment to start the minecraft launcher automatically

I'm working off a ubuntu 13.04 minimal install (debian should work almost identically - except maybe how you install jdk), and will list the necessary packages for that but you could easily do this with any other distribution. Starting with a minimal/CLI install will ensure that.

I'd prefer 32 bit here for better compatibility, but minecraft will let you set the view distance further on 64 bits.

The easiest way to install oracle's java is from a ppa, but the default cli only install does not support that yet

install `python-software-properties` and `software-properties-common` from apt, then run

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

to install java 7 easily - this downloads the installer script from webupd8's repositories. You can also install it directly from oracle - ubuntu's [java page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java) has more details

Now, lets install our basic graphical environment

```
sudo apt-get install xinit twm xterm
```

I'd probably also add openssh-server for administration

You don't want your minecraft user using sudo, so I'd suggest creating a second account at this point, and switching over to the new user. At this point, we have an Admin user, created when you install and the regular user, who will be playing minecraft

We need to download minecraft, and we can do this in the new user's home account. You can download minecraft with wget.

the ~/.xsession file determines what gets autostarted there should be no xsession file there now, so create one with `nano ~/.xsession`

Initially, I would just have the line `xterm` there, and start up minecraft from that xterm to see if it works - you may end up needing to install appropriate video card drivers. Once that is done, you can change the system to boot straight to minecraft - replace `xterm` with the line `java -jar /path/to/Minecraft.jar` in my case its ~/Minecraft.jar

Now, we can test this with startx - this should open up a minecraft loader window on a blank background. Since we have nothing else, and I am doing this on a vm, this is about as far as I can go here - if you have some arguements for minecraft, this is where you use them.

You also cannot logout, or shutdown the system without switching VTs and doing it from CLI once X is started. You *did* say kiosk mode, right?

At this point you need to start up, log in, and run startx as your new user. We can use a login manager to autologin as your user. Once this is set up, the ONLY way to log in as the admin user is to switch virtual terminals, you've been warned.

install `slim` from apt, and open up /etc/slim as your admin user - I use nano so its `sudo nano /etc/slim` . You need to uncomment out the lines that read `# default_user simone` and change it to your user and uncomment out `# auto_login          no` and change that no to yes. You can then reboot, and the system should reboot, start x automatically, and go into the minecraft loader.

If you need to tweak any settings at this point, switch virtual terminals, and do this as your admin user, using startx should you need x. You *could* disable virtual terminals, but this would make any changes you would need difficult - there's some things you can't do over x.

The total size of this is 1.4gb by my reconing

Comment: On Debian, here's how to install Oracle Java: http://www.webupd8.org/2012/06/how-to-install-oracle-java-7-in-debian.html (even from the same repo!)

Answer (score 0):

8GB? No problem!

Start with a server install, then do

```
apt-get -y install openjdk-7-jre
sudo mv /filename.sh /etc/init.d/
sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/filename.sh
sudo update-rc.d filename.sh defaults
```

Then make a shell script named `filename.sh` which does

```
java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar /pathto/minecraft_server.jar nogui
```

and replace `/pathto` with the directory where you saved `minecraft_server.jar`

Comment: This unfortunately solves half of it, how do you launch the CLIENT part of minecraft? I've just made a server of it...

Answer (score 0):

If you want a flash drive boot solution, then I would recommend [SLAX Linux](http://www.slax.org/). You can include the [openjdk module](http://www.slax.org/modules.php?detail=openjdk7&category=develop) and package minecraft. This way, you could boot off of the flash drive and play Minecraft on any computer.

Comment: Thanks, but I forgot to mention that it has to be a kiosk.